# Opengl Relative Z-buffer of Fragments

Tags: opengl

I understand that using

```
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
```

makes the object to render on top of any object, if they are closer to the camera.

I was wondering if there is anyway to modify such DepthFunction, so that I can have flexible rendering.

To be more specific, lets say there are 9 different faces, A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3.

What i want to do is that when rendered, A1, A2, A3 is rendered correctly. (closer to the camera is rendered on top.) and same for B and C.

However, regardless of the distance to the camera, B is always rendered on the top of A, and C is rendered on top of B, but A is rendered on top of C. which is A < B < C < A.

Will this be possible?

EDIT:

My idea is to generate a 3D Model for an "unrealistic figure". While there could be a way to achieve this in different ways, here I was wondering if there is a way to solve by modifying how depth function works.

[image]

Comment: I can not understand that `A<B<C<A`. Could you post some image?

Answer (score 1):

First, note that depth testing has to do with individual pixels, not objects.

Second, you can clear the depth buffer while leaving the color buffer intact. For example, if you wish to draw 2 groups of primitives and you wish the second group to be "on top" of the first, you can do:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
glDrawArrays(...) // draw the first group
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
glDrawArrays(...) // draw the second group
```

Each group will be depth tested against itself, but not against the other group. In this way you can implement a layered rendering strategy.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful reply!! Im really new to OpenGL. I get that I can draw A < B < C, but how could I draw C that goes below A?

Comment: I think we need a picture, that it's hard to understand.  :)

Comment: I have added a figure! Thanks for the help

Comment: Ha!  Maybe the developers of Monument Valley (Ustwo Games) can help!

I think you pull this off with an orthographic projection and a careful partition of the scene into layers.

Comment: Yeah my current try is exactly that, but i was hoping the camera angle can be little bit more free, so that the object can turn maybe 30 degrees in each direction, not stuck in a single spot.